# Parent of RPATH $ORIGIN

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I can set install rpath to be the working directory with the following command:
`set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")`
But is there a possibility to search for the shared libraries in the parent of the `$ORIGIN`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem?

Comment: "set install rpath to be the working directory with the following command" Nope, `$ORIGIN` doesn't refer to the working directory, but the directory containing the binary you set the rpath for; this is entirely independent of the working directory. As for the question: you can use `$ORIGIN` as part of a path, e.g. `$ORIGIN/..`

Comment: @kiner_shah My executable should be able to find shared libraries in the parent of the folder from which it is invoked

Comment: @fabian my problem is that if my working directory is the same as the one in which the file is located, everything works. Otherwise, I have the following error: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @КириллВолков do you use `dlopen` with relative paths?

Comment: [Here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling#recommendations) they note: `it should have its
dollar sign escaped with a backslash to have it end up with proper
syntax in the final executable`. Maybe it is just indeed unexpectedly expanded by cmake and you need `\$ORIGIN` or maybe `$$ORIGIN`.